# NFS mounts showing files from other mounts

Tags: nfs, nfs4

I have a server that holds ZFS snapshots that I export via NFS to the servers they are backing up so you can restore via a custom application written in-house.  The issue is as follows:

**NOTE: I am not using ZFS built-in NFS for a reason, so please don't tell me to use that!**

This is all NFS v4
The host is running CentOS 6.2
The client is running CentOS 5.7

I have 8 nfs servers started by default on the host.

On the backup server that holds the NFS shares, I can traverse the directory structure as deep as needed and see all expected files.

On the client, I can traverse the filesystem, but sometimes, and it really seems random, when I go 2 or more directories deep, I end up seeing the files from another server.

Here is an example:

```
[NFSSERVER /nfs/share]#  ls -l
total 60
drwx--x--x 30 root root 4096 Feb 25 00:15 20120225
drwx--x--x 30 root root 4096 Feb 26 00:05 20120226
drwx--x--x 30 root root 4096 Feb 27 00:06 20120227
.....
```

so on

```
[NFSCLIENT /app/backups]# ls -l
total 60
drwx--x--x 30 nobody nobody 4096 Mar  2 00:25 20120225/
drwx--x--x 30 nobody nobody 4096 Mar  2 00:25 20120226/
drwx--x--x 30 nobody nobody 4096 Mar  2 00:25 20120227/
......
```

so on

You can see those are identical, as they should be.

This is where the problem starts.  If i go into:

```
[NFSCLIENT /app/backups/20120225/home] #  ls -l
```

When I run this ls -l on the client *sometimes* I see the proper files, sometimes I see the home dir of another server.

If I got to `[NFSSERVER /nfs/share/20120225/home]# ls -l`

When I run this ls -l I see the proper files.  If I delete a folder in /nfs/share/ I can see the result on the client immediately.  It is only when i go deeper that I see these "cross-mounted" filesystems.

Here is a portion of my /etc/exports (hostnames changed)

```
/nfs *.domain.com(fsid=0,ro,nohide,no_root_squash)
/nfs/server1/20120308 *.domain.com(ro,nohide,no_root_squash)
/nfs/server1/20120309 *.domain.com(ro,nohide,no_root_squash)
/nfs/server1/20120310 *.domain.com(ro,nohide,no_root_squash)
/nfs/server1/20120311 *.domain.com(ro,nohide,no_root_squash)
/nfs/server2/20120308 *.domain.com(ro,nohide,no_root_squash)
/nfs/server2/20120309 *.domain.com(ro,nohide,no_root_squash)
/nfs/server2/20120310 *.domain.com(ro,nohide,no_root_squash)
/nfs/server2/20120311 *.domain.com(ro,nohide,no_root_squash)
/nfs/server3/20120204 *.domain.com(ro,nohide,no_root_squash)
/nfs/server3/20120205 *.domain.com(ro,nohide,no_root_squash)
/nfs/server3/20120206 *.domain.com(ro,nohide,no_root_squash)
/nfs/server3/20120207 *.domaincom(ro,nohide,no_root_squash)
```

IF I remove all lines from etc exports EXCEPT the one that is cross-mounting, then reload the exports file (ie, only leaving one entry in /etc/exports), it shows all of the proper directories on the client machine.

So, stale NFS handles?  More NFS servers running by default?  Something else?  Any ideas?  I've been banging my head for a couple weeks now on this one.

**UPDATE**

This is the line of code my script runs that is setting up the directories that are being exported:

```
mount -t ext4 -o noload,ro /dev/zvol/backups/$HOST@$DATE"-00" /nfs/$HOST/$DATE
```

The /nfs/$HOST/$DATE folders are the ones being exported (as you can see in the exports file above)

Comment: Are you running ZFS on Linux?

Comment: yes, which is why i'm avoiding the nfs that is built in for now, it's not yet stable from my experience.

Comment: If i understood you correctly, would i be right in saying that the  inode number is shown as different on a directory mounted from NFS - on different clients?

Comment: Are you using autofs/automount on the client?

Comment: @ColdT, not sure if I'm following your train of thought. no automount/autofs

Answer (score 1):

so it seems it was the wildcard exports, which, if you read the man page, are not recommended.  I'd read that before but for some reason didn't fix it.  I still think this is a "bug" and it *should* work in theory but in practice, it doesn't.

Hope this helps others.

Example of my new exports file:

```
/nfs server1.a2hosting.com(fsid=0,ro,nohide,no_root_squash)
/nfs/server1/20120320 server1.a2hosting.com(ro,nohide,no_root_squash)
```

Comment: it also wont take a specific ip i noticed. like 192.168.1.20. it needs to be 192.168.1.20/24 (or whatever mask used)